# Windows 7 taskbar disable "show if mouse-over"

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

My default is auto-hide windows 7 taskbar.

**1.** I can show the taskbar when I get my mouse over the line on the edge.

OR

**2.** I can show it when I press the windows button.

**I would like to disable the 1st option and keep the 2nd.**

Ideally, I would like to delete the windows taskbar line with it but that's not the priority. Some apps seems to work that way. I would be glad for any tweaks or tips.

---

EDIT: Example of how I can imagine it works.

My windows toolbar is hidden at the top of the screen, just thin line is visible. 
I still want the taskbar to be there avaible. To pop out when i press the windows button.

But I want to disable the option when i get my mouse at the top line which cause the windows taskbar pop out.

It does not matter to me if the thin line is visible or not. I just dont want the taskbar to show when i use my mouse.

---

Hope it clearly describes my idea.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25572/Hiding-the-Taskbar-and-Startmenu-start-orb-in-Wind) you find the source code [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) to do that.

[Here](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/79667-remove-taskbar-100-a.html) someone already edited the code to do what you want. "*I can remove your taskbar 100% but you will still be able to open the Start Menu with the Windows key on your keyboard if that's any good to you.*"

Comment: Thank you, I have tried it but its just a half way of what I wanted it. I'm gonna edit my question with more details.